# stuck in functionaltiy of block user betweeen each other using firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child(Common.USERS);
       query .orderByKey().equalTo(Common.BLOCKED_USERS).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String temp = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildren());
                Log.d("My Msg", "Value event change = "+ temp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

the query to retrieve unblock user from firebase but not work

Comment: Please don't post pictures of textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. In the case of your database, you can get this text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @Ribo my question was i am making the androidsocial app using firebase database. in which user has block each other profile as a feature . my problem is i was stuck in retrieve the user who are not blocked .